# Biblatex replace title with alternate field

Tags: biblatex, biber

## Question:

I would like to replace the biblatex+biber title when a `.bib` entry does not contain a title. For example, if I have the entry:

```
@article{key123,
  author = {Name AA and Name BB},
  title = {Article title name},
  Year = {2016},
  revjournal = {Journal Name},
}
```

I want to replace the

Name AA and Name BB. “Article Title Name”. In: (2016).

with

Name AA and Name BB. “Article Title Name”. Under review at: *Journal Name* (2016).

## What I have tried:

I have attempted to map `revjournal` to `usera` with the following:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
    \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
      \map{
        \step[fieldsource=revjournal]
        \step[fieldset=usera,origfieldval]
    }
  }
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{usera}{%
  \iffieldundef{title}{%
    \mkbibacro{Under review at}\addcolon\space#1%
  }{}%
}
```

But that does nothing. Perhaps there is a better way to replace/overwrite biblatex fields?

## MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber,firstinits=true]{biblatex}
\DeclareSourcemap{
    \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
      \map{
        \step[fieldsource=revjournal]
        \step[fieldset=usera,origfieldval]
    }
  }
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{usera}{%
  \iffieldundef{title}{%
    \mkbibacro{Under review at}\addcolon\space{#1}%
  }{}%
}

\begin{filecontents}{./pubs.bib}
@article{key123,
  author = {Name AA and Name BB},
  title = {Article title name},
  Year = {2016},
  revjournal = {Journal Name},
  }
\end{filecontents}
\bibliography{./pubs.bib}
\begin{document}

\fullcite{key123}
\end{document}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an alternative solution to the problem. Biblatex provides the field `pubstate` to record the publication status of journal articles.

Thus I suggest to keep the standard `journaltitle` (or the  bibtex `journal` field) and to add the `pubstate= {under review}` information to the entry.

Thus the bibtex entry looks like

```
@article{key123,
  author = {Name AA and Name BB},
  title = {Article title name},
  Year = {2016},
  journal = {Journal Name},
  pubstate = {under review},
  }
```

Then, to process the  information and typeset the output in  the desired format use:

```
\def\jmlarson@ur{under review}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {\iffieldequals{substate}{\jmlarson@ur}{\printtext{Under review at\intitlepunct}}{}\clearfield{pubstate}}
    {\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}%
}
```

The trick is to redefine the macro that typeset "In" to put the right text for the appropriate entires,  and to clear the information in `pubstate` (so it is not printed twice).

With the provided MWE, this results in:

[image]

Comment: This looks promising. But for some reason, any pubstate seems to catch the "under review" condition in the redefined `in:` macro. I tried to add `pubstate= {to appear}` but it still uses the `pubstate={under review}`. See the modified MWE above. (See commented out alternative that I was trying to build.)

Comment: @jmlarson modified the answer to address the problem.

Comment: I see that I should not have changed the question. I have accepted this because it certainly answered the original question.

Answer (score 0):

A more robust result, courtesy of @moewe is to use:

```
\iffieldequalstr{pubstate}{under review}
```

and not declare any macros. For more justification, see here:

[Biblatex: iffieldequals appears to return true for false conditions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290924/biblatex-iffieldequals-appears-to-return-true-for-false-conditions)