# Biblatex: iffieldequals appears to return true for false conditions

Tags: biblatex

## Question:

I am using `\iffieldequals{pubstate}{str}` to test the `pubstate` of two different `.bib` entries. But even `pubstate={foo}`, it still behaves as if `pubstate={str}`. This is in response to the answer to the question:

[Biblatex replace title with alternate field](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290823/biblatex-replace-title-with-alternate-field)

## M(N)WE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber,firstinits=true]{biblatex}
\newbibmacro{ur}{under review}
\newbibmacro{ta}{to appear}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {\iffieldequals{pubstate}{ur}{\printtext{Under review at\intitlepunct}}{}\clearfield{pubstate}}
    % {\iffieldequals{pubstate}{ur}{\printtext{Under review at\intitlepunct}}{\iffieldequals{pubstate}{ta}{\printtext{To appear in\intitlepunct}}{}}\clearfield{pubstate}}
    {\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}%
}

\begin{filecontents}{./pubs.bib}
@article{key1,
  author = {Name AA and Name BB},
  title = {Article title name one},
  Year = {2016},
  journal = {Journal Name One},
  pubstate = {under review},
  }

@article{key2,
  author = {Name CC and Name DD},
  title = {Article title name two},
  Year = {2016},
  journal = {Journal Name Two},
  pubstate = {to appear},
  }
\end{filecontents}
\bibliography{./pubs.bib}
\begin{document}

\fullcite{key1}

\fullcite{key2}
\end{document}
```

## Output:

[image: incorrect_image]
The output should not have "Under review" for `key2` because it has `pubstate={to appear}`.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: Use

```
\iffieldequalstr{pubstate}{under review}
```

or

```
\newcommand*\ur{under review}
\iffieldequals{pubstate}{\ur}
```

or

```
\newcommand*\ur{under review}
\iffieldequalcs{pubstate}{ur}
```

Where the first option is the preferred here I think.

---

Accoring to [the documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) (p. 182)

> `\iffieldequals{<field>}{<macro>}{<true>}{<false>}` Expands to
>   *true* if the value of the `<field>` is equal to the definition of *macro*, and to *false* otherwise.

The value of the field in your case is `under review`.

If you issue `\iffieldequals{pubstate}{ur}` `ur` isn't even a macro and it evaluates to *false* (indeed I even got an error in one case).

What you need is a macro that expands to exactly `under review`, the easiest way is `\def{\ur}{under review}`, but `\newcommand*\ur{under review}` also works; on the other hand `\newcommand\ur{under review}` doesn't work because it defines a long macro.
In that case you use

```
\iffieldequals{pubstate}{\ur}
```

What's more

```
\newbibmacro{ur}{under review}
```

does not actually define a macro called `\ur`, but a long macro called `\abx@macro@ur`. `\newbibmacro*{ur}{under review}` defines a "normal" macro called `\abx@macro@ur`

Alternatively, you can use `\iffieldequalcs` where you don't give a macro, but a control sequence name (the macro without the backslash)

```
\iffieldequals{pubstate}{ur}
```

This has the advantage of not creating the overhead of additional macros. And it makes the condition slightly easier to understand and read in the code.
The best solution here seems to be to use `\iffieldequalstr` to check if the field is equal to the string given in the second argument

```
\iffieldequalstr{pubstate}{under review}
```